# Ionic - couldn't launch Uber app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to launch the Uber app from the Ionic app, but it fails to launch it. I have already installed Cordova inappbrowser plugin. Here is my code snippet:

```
 window.open('uber://?action=setPickup&pickup=my_location&dropoff[latitude]=' + $scope.listing.latitude + '&dropoff[longitude]=' + $scope.listing.longitude, '_system', 'location=yes');
```

Comment: Have you whitelisted the url? https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#intent-whitelist

Comment: This is the only line I have added to the config.xml file.

<access origin="uber:*" launch-external="yes"/>

Comment: That should be OK, but maybe try replacing the `<access />` tag with  `<allow-intent href="uber.*" />` not sure it will work but worth a try

Comment: I will add that and see if that'll work. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: did you find a solution to this? Why do you need the inapp browser?